# flot disappears after refreshing the page (IE8)

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, internet-explorer-8, flot

At first, when realizing that flot (jQuery plugin) sometimes disappears on IE8, I right away downloaded the latest [excanvas.js](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/source/list) and replaced the old one supplied with flot.

This solved the problem partially, I also added zoom:1 to the canvas css selector, in order to force elements with display:inline-block (as discussed in [enter link description here](http://shades-of-orange.com/post/2011/09/08/Rendering-problem-with-flot-07-and-excanvas-in-IE8.aspx)).

but still, IE8 doesn't show the graph after a refresh is done, nevertheless, when I visit the URL by clicking 'Go', it works. (this is very odd to me).

Any suggestions? workarounds?

Comment: Is there any way you can show some of the code or perhaps an example page you're working on? With things like this it could end up being anything, so any extra information helps